# C++ - too much hints during writing a code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense, platformio

I've started to use Visual Studio Code + PlatformIO. Generally it's fine for me, but one thing is annoying me: too wide hints during writing.

For instance, if I type `Serial.`, I'm presented with a frame with hints. It should be a list of visible methods possible to use with object `Serial`: `.print`, `.println`, `.read`, etc. Unfortunately, here I see all possible methods, available in my system, from all libraries etc:

[image: hints for Serial. object]

It makes such helps useless. What to do with it?

---

I tried to compare my settings with colleague, who hasn't such problem and found one difference. I'm not sure if it is a reason, but maybe?
Viz: in my project, inside .vscode folder there is a section c_cpp_properties.json, here is a configuration of extension C/C++ Intellisense, right? And here it is:  **"intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"**,
According to help clang-x64 is for MAC OS. But I haven't MAC! I installed this software on PC with W10, for windows this value should be msvc-x64. But how to change it? I tried just edit this field, but after restart VSC previous value is restored.

Comment: Visual studio code has two preferences. One is per project, and the other is per global. Maybe you just edited project preferences and checked global preferences after restarting VSC.

Comment: If you want a smart, compiler guided completer, you should look into clangd. It is an on-the-fly compilation server for IDEs, with good integration with Visual Studio Code. It even shows compilation errors on real time.

Comment: if intellisense is configured incorrectly it will fall back to a dumb mode where the suggestions it offers aren't context sensitive. Check for warnings about missing header files. Also see the setup instructions: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

Comment: that's an answer Alan

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 more of a guess based on incomplete information, if you want to make it into an answer feel free

Comment: if you're not sure about it that's even more reason not to dodge the peer review system Alan

Comment: Thx for all answers. I'm new user of VSC, without any experience with such platforms, so maybe something is not clear enough for me, but:
@AlanBirtles - I changed nothing during installing this extension, just installed it (also tried already to reinstall). Where should I look for such warnings?

Comment: @openingnow - i tried again to edit, save, exit and reopen VSC. Then I went to this file, it opened with correct, edited value and on my eyes it changed into wrong one.

Comment: Errors should be listed in the problems window, you probably do need to do some configuration in order to get intellisense working

Comment: @lvella - sounds interesting, unfortunately can't test it. After installing it is reported as conflicted with current C/C++ Intellisense, which is required by PlatformIO, which I'm using. Too many "which", but I believe it is understandable, what I mean :)

Comment: If it's not solved by now, check settings -> "C/C++" (in "extensions") -> "Intelli Sense Engine". The "tag parser" mode is not context aware, the "default" mode is. Changing it to default might help, if nothing else is broken.